# There is a error:1464 when I using the SQL Server 2016 "New Availability Group"

Tags: sql-server

The last step of "AlwaysOn High Availability wizard", when joining database A to availability group AG on one server.

The error info is:

> Database A is not in a recovering state which is required for a mirror database or secondary database.The remote database must be restored using WITH NORECOVERY.(Microsoft SQL Server,Error:1464)

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/359a635f-442c-49e6-8ba0-84b638a44e74/alwayson-availability-group-database-restore?forum=sqldisasterrecovery

Comment: Yes.I should backup the database and T-Log with NORECOVERY

Comment: A database must be in the FULL recovery mode   &    
A database should have at least one FULL backup   &    
A database needs to have at least one T-Log backup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a requirement that DB must be restored on secondary replicas with NORECOVERY option.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/manually-prepare-a-secondary-database-for-an-availability-group-sql-server